# Expresso Store 4.1 invoice unpaid

Tags: expresso-store, payment-gateway

We use EE4 and Store 4.1. For the time being costumer get the goods with an invoice. We use payment gateway "Manual".

I have two questions:

"Manual" stores an order in the backend as paid (Paid? Yes). But we would need it stored "no" (unpaid). Anything we can do?

How difficult is it to make a payment gateway named "Invoice" (or in German "Rechnung")? Maybe out of the files of "Manual"?

Thanks for some advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Manual" stores an order in the backend as paid (Paid? Yes). But we would need it stored "no" (unpaid). Anything we can do?

Right now, modifying the "Credit Card Payment Method" setting to "authorize only" should cause these to show as "unpaid". That might not be OK if you're also taking credit card payments. We might update this behavior in a future update to un-link them.

> How difficult is it to make a payment gateway named "Invoice" (or in German "Rechnung")? Maybe out of the files of "Manual"?

Very easy! You can use manual and just update the class name, file name, and description. This is also a good way to start: https://github.com/devdemon/store_check.

Comment: Thank you Matt, yes un-link them.